# How do I find all records matching a list of Ids in ebean and play framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a model class that has an id per record. And I have a list of id's that I want to search from that table.

Do I need to build a SQL statement dynamically and pass it to the Finder object or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to build a query using `Expr.in(String propertyName, Collection<?> values)`

Other options are : `Expr.in(String propertyName, Object[] values)` or `Expr.in(String propertyName, Query<?> subQuery)`

[API reference.](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Expr.html)